# Function returning None for recursive function for factorial function

Tags: python, if-statement, factorial

I'm trying to write a code that returns the factorial of the input num but this code is returning "None" when I run it, I'm not sure why.

```
def factorial(num):
    if type(num) is not int():
        return None
    elif num == 0:
        return 1
    elif num < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return num * factorial(num - 1)

factorial5 = factorial(5)
print(factorial5)
```

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that one of the two branches with `return None` is taking effect?

Comment: You need to remove the parenthesis from `int`.  Actually you should use: `if not isinstance(num, int):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis .. see the correction from `int()` to `int`:

```
def factorial(num):
    if type(num) is not int:
        return None
    elif num == 0:
        return 1
    elif num < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return num * factorial(num - 1)

factorial5 = factorial(5)
print(factorial5)
```

NOTE: ran with Python3

```
120
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies in the condition `type(num)` is not `int()`. The correct way to check if num is not an instance of int is by comparing its type with int using the `isinstance()` function.

```
def factorial(num):
    if not isinstance(num, int):
        return None
    elif num == 0:
        return 1
    elif num < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return num * factorial(num - 1)

factorial5 = factorial(5)
print(factorial5)
```